# Русские символы XML в Python3

Tags: python, xml, кодировка, строки, python-3.x

Пишу программу, которая работает с xml файлами. И возникла проблема с записью символов в файл. Функция для записи выглядит следующим образом:

```
def addPost(name, text):
  print(name + text)
  tree = ET.parse('db.xml')
  root = tree.getroot()
  post = ET.SubElement(root,'post')
  post.set('num', str(getCnt()))
  nameElem = ET.SubElement(post, 'name')
  nameElem.text = name
  textElem = ET.SubElement(post, 'text')
  textElem.text = text
  tree.write('db.xml')
```

Проблема заключается в следующем: при записи в файл в нём вместо обычной строки появляются следующие символы:

```
&amp;#1056;&amp;#1072;&amp;#1073;&amp;#1086;&amp;#1090;&amp;#1072;
```

Плюс сам скрипт меняет кодировку `xml` файла с `utf-8` на `ansii`. Как с этим справиться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
parser = ET.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
root = ET.parse("file.xml", parser=parser)

tree.write("out.xml", encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: не нужно явно кодировку указывать *при чтении* xml, иначе может ошибка возникнуть, если входной файл другую кодировку использует. Входная кодировка никак не связана с кодировкой в `.write()` методе.